# bigquery how to get device information

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

My Google analytics interface displays reports by device i.e. right down to this kind of detail: Huawei Y330-U07 Ascend Y330

However, the bigquery data I have behind it doesn't shows - but it shows right down to the browser, operating system and screen resolution
does anyone know how i can get the same detail as what google analytics gives?
I thought the two would be equivelant

Answer (score 2):

For  a certain level you can use field `device.mobileDeviceBranding`

This is present only in recent tables.

Otherwise since you are already paying for Premium Analytics, you can ask the support to add the fields. The schema is extended constantly.

Comment: device.mobileDeviceBranding gives me the brand. but not the model number - how do I get the Phone model details?

Comment: are you able to help me?

Comment: you need to ask the support for further deep information as it's not available on the schema